# Redirect to log in page if session does not exist in PHP

Tags: php

So I have this page that can only be accessed if a user is logged in. If not, he will be redirected to the home page (if the user visits the page directly). What I want to do, is to redirect the user to the login page, and if it the login is successful, then will get redirected to the page.

Comment: Cool. What have you tried?

Comment: Start with the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - and from the beginning also http://php.net/manual/en/index.php there's a LOT of great stuff on there and will give you many hours of enjoyment.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I can answer that for you: "nothing" and are wanting to be fed like "deer in a kiddy park". Also ignoring comments given here.

Comment: This question has shown zero effort/code. "User" from where, database? Sure sounds like it. Or are you just ignoring us here and expect us to write it all out for you? If that's the case, then you'll get back what you posted; nothing really. This goes both ways you know.

Comment: Please note, that this is not a free
   code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers
   (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics
   on [How to ask a good
   question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards,
   please update your question with the code you have written thus far
   in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Basically and in a simplified way, the concepts are:

First, start the session inside all pages using sessions:

```
session_start();
```

Then, do your check in your pages:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['is-user-logged'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

In Login in page:

```
if($_POST){
    // .. Process your form here and check if the user submitted valid credentials.

    $_SESSION['is-user-logged'] = 1;
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}
```

On your logout page:

```
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");
exit;
```

Comment: No, apparently you did not get my question. I have a page, that can only be accessed from the logged in users. If the user is not logged in and visits the page, he will go back to the login page and complete the form, in order to access the page.

Comment: @ArioRakip That's exactly what this code does...?

Comment: I know, it just redirects to one specific page. I want it to redirect to the page the user accessed directly.

Comment: just adapt the header function, instead of home.php put the page you want, you can do this dynamically